# Bind MySQL to IP when installing

Tags: mysql, linux, ip, bind

When I install Mysql using apt-get it binds to the localhost. I have to manually change the bind address. 
Is there a way  I can set bind address at the time of install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, You need to change that in in `my.cnf` after installation and then restart `MySQL Server`.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to localhost is the default is for security.

If you want less secure configure you are required then reconfigure your my.cnf file manually.